# Specify the gcc version for bitbake meta-toolchain

Tags: yocto

I'm just starting to learn Yocto 1.8.

The `bitbake meta-toolchain` ran fine as described in the documentation and generated the appropriate installation script. However, `bitbake` picked a version of GCC that I don't want.
What is the recommended way to tell `bitbake` which version of GCC to pick for the `bitbake meta-toolchain` build?

Answer (score 6):

Just to keep the record complete.

The exact GCC version is specified in the machine/.conf file as:

```
# This version is Yocto-branch dependent
PREFERRED_VERSION_gcc-cross-${TARGET_ARCH} ?= "5.2%"
```